# Algorithm to extract subgraph of graph induced by a set of nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have an undirected graph `G=(V,E)` and I want to extract a subgraph of `G` induced by a set of nodes which is subset of `V`. Now I am looking for the algorithm to do this in Python?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? The definition of an induced subgraph should tell you all you need to do: Take all the nodes in the subset and all edges whose incident nodes are both in the subset.

Comment: This question fits better in other stack exchange communities like Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or Mathematics (https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph should be represented as a dictionary, where the key is the number of the vertex and the value is adjacency list for that vertex, represented as a set.

Now you are given `S = {s1, s2, ..., sn}` such that `S` is a subset of `V`. Build a dictionary to represent the induced graph. It should contain all vertices in `S`, each with empty adjacency lists.

First, we initialize `H`:

```
H = {}  # Initialize empty dictionary.

for si in S:
    H[si] = set()
```

Then we fill `H` with the correct edges:

```
for si in S:
    adj = G[si]
    for v in adj:
        if v in S: 
            H[si].add(v) 
            H[v].add(si)
```

Complexity: O(V + E).